# Irregular Range in excel AVERAGEIF function

Tags: excel, excel-2010, average, range

I would like to do a AVERAGEIF function in a line like that to obtain "X":

```
    gen1   vgen1   gen2    vgen2   gen3    vgen3    2nmean
     2n      2      1n       1      2n      2,2       X
```

However I can´t select irregular ranges, this i my code in "X" cell:

=AVERAGEIF(gen1,gen2,gen3;"=*2n";vgen1,vgen2,vgen3)

To apply in excel (Excel 2010):

=AVERAGEIF(A2,C2,E2;"=*2n";B2,D2,F2)

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you could use simply:

```
=AVERAGEIF(A2:E2;"=*2n";B2:F2)
```